# 'b' is getting passed when sending string from client to server in python while trying FTP implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ftp

I am trying to implement to implement FTP where I want to send Filename to server from client, I have tried below code, when I give file name as myText.txt but server is receiving as 'b"myText.txt'"

Can you please help me how can I get rid of b ?
This is the output on server:

This is server code:

```
import socket                   # Import socket module
port = 60000                    # Reserve a port for your service.
socketObj = socket.socket()     #Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()     # Get local machine name
socketObj.bind((host, port))    # Bind to the port
socketObj.listen(5)             # Now wait for client connectionection.
print ('Server listening....')

while True:
    connection, addr = socketObj.accept()     # Establish connectionection with client.
    print ('Got connectionection from', addr)
    data = connection.recv(1024)
    print('Server received request for FTS of',(data))

    filename=(repr(data))
    f = open(filename,'rb')
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
       connection.send(l)
       print('Sent ',repr(l))
       l = f.read(1024)
    f.close()

    print('Done sending')
    connection.send(('Thank you for connectionecting').encode())
    connection.close()
```

This is the client code

```
import socket                   # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()     # Get local machine name
port = 60000                    # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
fileNeeded = input("What File do you need, please enter the name:")
s.send(fileNeeded.encode())

fileToBeSaved = input("Enter file name to save requested file")

with open(fileToBeSaved, 'wb') as f:
    print ('file opened')
    while True:
        print('receiving data...')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print((data))
        if not data:
            break
        # write data to a file
        f.write(data)

f.close()
print('Successfully got the file')
s.close()
print('connection closed')
```

The following is received in server:
Server received request for FTS of b'mytext.txt'

Comment: If you get rid of `repr(data)` you'll solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) method to convert bytes into a string:

Change:

```
filename=(repr(data))
```

to:

```
filename=repr(data).decode()
```